Writing a firestore security rule for "Subscribers" collection
I have a simple website and I want to give users the option to subscribe to my mailing list. Nothing more, just entering their email, press "Subscribe" and their email gets stored into my "Subscribers" firestore collection.
This is my subscribe funstion:
export default async function subscribe(email) {
    if(!email || email.trim() ==""){
      return;
    }
    await setDoc(doc(db, "Subscribers", email), {
      date: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
    });
}

Nothing fancy - just "Subscribers" collection, doc is unique email and I also save the date where users have subscribed. It works perfectly and I am happy with it.
The problem I have is with the security rules. Obviously I want to allow anyone to subscribe, and also if the user is already subscribed, I will just update the date in the "Subscribers" collection.
Those are my firestore rules:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /Subscribers/{email}{
        allow create: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['date'])
        allow update: if request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['date']);
        allow read: if false;
    }
  }
}

Those rules work fine - obviously it allows create and update and I am ok with that.
However is my data safe? Is there anything else I can do to protect "Subscribers" collection from malicious attempts? Is there a way to verify that the request to to update doc with docId email has the same email as the docId?

It's impossible to say if your data is "safe".  There could be any number of ways for someone to get a hold of data that you didn't intend (governed by security rules or not), and we can't proactively anticipate and discuss all of them.  If you want your data to be "safe", you need to very explicitly define the circumstances and rules where access is allowed, and implement them using the technologies that provide the coverage you want.  This could be through security rules or backend code that only you control.

@DougStevenson I guess I wanted to know if there is anything more I can do for a simple "Subscribers" collection from a security rules perspective - given that I store only one field (date) and given that my key is the subscriber's email

There is only something that can be done if your application's requirements says there is something to be done.  Why write code that doesn't serve a specific well-defined purpose?

Can you more clearly define what "malicious attempt" means? e.g. you can use rules to, for example, prevent an unauthenticated user from writing to that node, along with reading from it. OR you could set up a rules that only allows users with certain UID's to write to it. The question is pretty vague as mentioned above so hard to provide a specific answer.

As Doug already commented: "secure" is not an absolute state, and you always need to be explicit about what specific type of abuse/attack you want to secure/protect against.
For example, based on the code/rules you shared you are using the user's email as the document ID, but nothing in your rules enforces that. So that means that a user can write under any email value they want, including a non-valid email or somebody else's email. Of that is something you want to prevent, you can do so with this additional clause in your create and update rules:
email == request.auth.token.email

This is just one specific scenario, and you'll need to identify each such scenario you want to secure/protect against.
